# Why does reading from CSV fail with NumberFormatException?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I use Spark 1.6.0 and Scala 2.10.5.

```
$ spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext   
import sqlContext.implicits._    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}

val bankSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("age", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("job", StringType, true),
  StructField("marital", StringType, true),
  StructField("education", StringType, true),
  StructField("default", StringType, true),
  StructField("balance", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("housing", StringType, true),
  StructField("loan", StringType, true),
  StructField("contact", StringType, true),
  StructField("day", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("month", StringType, true),
  StructField("duration", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("campaign", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("pdays", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("previous", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("poutcome", StringType, true),
  StructField("y", StringType, true)))

val market_details = sqlContext.
  read.
  format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
  option("header", "true").
  schema(bankSchema).
  load("/user/sachnil.2007_gmail/Project1_dataset_bank-full.csv")    
market_details.registerTempTable("phone_table")    
val temp = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM phone_table").show()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
17/05/14 06:11:42 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"" at 
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at 
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) at 
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) at 
    scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229) at 
    scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31) at 
    com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TypeCast$.castTo(TypeCast.scala:61) at 
    com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$2.apply(CsvRelation.scala:121) at 
    com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$2.apply(CsvRelation.scala:108) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327) at 
    scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308) at 
    scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) at 
    scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) at 
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157) at 
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252) at 
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212) at 
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
```

The CSV contents looks like:

```
"age";"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";151;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
33;"entrepreneur";"married";"secondary";"no";2;"yes";"yes";"unknown";5;"may";76;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
47;"blue-collar";"married";"unknown";"no";1506;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";92;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have laid out your post more in line with SO's expectations; it's still not perfect, not lease due to the long line of code but I'm not familiar with the language so I didn't want to change that.  Also, I remove your plea for help at the end because that is a given and not encouraged on here, however; you haven't actually asked a question.  Please outline what you actually want help with and what you have tried so far to solve the problem and you may find you'll get the help you are seeking.

Comment: Actually,  I need to know where I am going wrong in loading the CSV to the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 1.6.0 is so old that almost no one supports it these days (unless it's part of a commercial support). I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version 2.1.1 that gives you plenty of choices.

---

Let me start off with this: in my custom 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT build *loading your CSV file just works* so I think you *may* have ran into some unsupported feature of spark-csv in the version you use.

Please note that spark-csv module has been integrated in Spark as of Spark 2+ (one of the many reasons why you should upgrade your Spark).

---

If you insist on a custom schema (which you could let Spark to figure out itself when using `inferSchema` option) use at least the DSL to cut the keystrokes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val bankSchema = StructType(
  $"age".int ::
  $"job".string ::
  $"marital".string ::
  $"education".string ::
  $"default".string ::
  $"balance".int ::
  $"housing".string ::
  $"loan".string ::
  $"contact".string ::
  $"day".int ::
  $"month".string ::
  $"duration".int ::
  $"campaign".int ::
  $"pdays".int ::
  $"previous".int ::
  $"poutcome".string ::
  $"y".string ::
  Nil)

scala> println(bankSchema.treeString)
root
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- job: string (nullable = true)
 |-- marital: string (nullable = true)
 |-- education: string (nullable = true)
 |-- default: string (nullable = true)
 |-- balance: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- housing: string (nullable = true)
 |-- loan: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contact: string (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- campaign: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pdays: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- previous: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- poutcome: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
```

---

If you develop Spark applications using Scala, I'd strongly recommend describing schema using a case class and leveraging encoders (it's again Spark 2+).

```
case class Market(
  age: Int,
  job: String,
  marital: String,
  education: String,
  default: String,
  balance: Int,
  housing: String,
  loan: String,
  contact: String,
  day: Int,
  month: String,
  duration: Int,
  campaign: Int,
  pdays: Int,
  previous: Int,
  poutcome: String,
  y: String)
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
scala> val bankSchema = Encoders.product[Market]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: `default` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as field name
- root class: "Market"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:611)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:609)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:609)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
  ... 48 elided
```

(In this particular case it is not possible due to the reserved keyword `default` which you may therefore want to avoid in your hand-built schema too).

---

Once you have the schema reading gives no errors with the sample you've included in the question:

```
val marketDetails = spark.
  read.
  schema(bankSchema).
  option("header", true).
  option("delimiter", ";").
  csv("market_details.csv")

scala> marketDetails.show
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
|age|         job|marital|education|default|balance|housing|loan|contact|day|month|duration|campaign|pdays|previous|poutcome|  y|
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
| 58|  management|married| tertiary|     no|   2143|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|     261|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 44|  technician| single|secondary|     no|     29|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|     151|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 33|entrepreneur|married|secondary|     no|      2|    yes| yes|unknown|  5|  may|      76|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 47| blue-collar|married|  unknown|     no|   1506|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|      92|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
```

---

What I really like about Spark SQL is that you can stick to using pure SQL if that's your preferred "language" in Spark.

```
val q = """
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW phone_table
  USING csv
  OPTIONS (
    inferSchema true,
    header true,
    delimiter ';',
    path 'market_details.csv')"""

// execute the above query and discard the result
// we're only interested in the side effect of creating a temp view
sql(q).collect

scala> sql("select * from phone_table").show
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
|age|         job|marital|education|default|balance|housing|loan|contact|day|month|duration|campaign|pdays|previous|poutcome|  y|
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
| 58|  management|married| tertiary|     no|   2143|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|     261|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 44|  technician| single|secondary|     no|     29|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|     151|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 33|entrepreneur|married|secondary|     no|      2|    yes| yes|unknown|  5|  may|      76|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 47| blue-collar|married|  unknown|     no|   1506|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|      92|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
+---+------------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
```

PROTIP: Use `spark-sql` and you can leave Scala aside completely.

Comment: I cannot upgrade my Spark due to environment restrictions. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You'd be surprised how much you're mistaken and you can use whatever Spark version **you** want (and the cluster environment has nothing to the version of Spark in use). It's just sbt-assembly away.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski -- _"Spark 1.6.0 is so old that almost no one supports it these days."_ > CDH ships with Spark 1.6.0 and I believe Cloudera has a **large** market share of "support" _(of course, the trick is that they have back-ported most of the bug fixes -- and regressions -- of the later 1.6.x while pretending it's still a 1.6.0)_

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Correct! They have to support their clients so I'm not surprised they do. The point is that Spark 1.6.0 is no longer supported by **the** source, i.e. the Spark project itself.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two issues here:

1. **CSV delimiter**

Your CSV data uses **;** as delimiter, you should add the following

```
.option("delimiter", ";")
```

To the read operation in order to use instruct spark to use the right delimiter

```
val market_details = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.schema(bankSchema)
.option("delimiter", ";")
.load("/user/sachnil.2007_gmail/Project1_dataset_bank-full.csv")
```

More info about *csv format* [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

> delimiter: by default columns are delimited using , but delimiter can be set to any character

2. **Input data includes quote sign (")**

Your input data includes un-needed **"**
Please remove the " from your csv input file, and run it again (PSB example input):

```
age;job;marital;education;default;balance;housing;loan;contact;day;month;duration;campaign;pdays;previous;poutcome;y
58;management;married;tertiary;no;2143;yes;no;unknown;5;may;261;1;-1;0;unknown;no
44;technician;single;secondary;no;29;yes;no;unknown;5;may;151;1;-1;0;unknown;no
33;entrepreneur;married;secondary;no;2;yes;yes;unknown;5;may;76;1;-1;0;unknown;no
47;blue-collar;married;unknown;no;1506;yes;no;unknown;5;may;92;1;-1;0;unknown;no
```

[Here you can find spark-sql-csv-examples](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-sql-csv-examples/)

The *Baby Names* example uses the following CSV input (title, follow by samples, without the quote sign):

```
Year,First Name,County,Sex,Count
2013,GAVIN,ST LAWRENCE,M,9
2013,LEVI,ST LAWRENCE,M,9
2013,LOGAN,NEW YORK,M,44
```

Comment: I tried using .option("delimiter", ";") but still i am facing error:    scala> val temp = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM phone_table").show()
17/05/14 09:33:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)

Comment: scala> val temp = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM phone_table").show()
17/05/14 09:33:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)

Comment: @Sachinjuneja - updated my answer and added another issue which should be fixed (the quote (") sign in the input)

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working now. I removed quote. I did this manually in CSV file and then load it to dataframe. Is there is any possibility to do it programmatically?